# уровНЕЙ или уровЕНЬ

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать подзаголовок: "Один из самых высоких в мире уровень чувствительности" или "Один из самых высоких в мире уровней чувствительности"? Мне кажется, оба варианта верные, смотря за какой член предложения принять слово "уровень". 
Обоснуйте, пожалуйста, ответ. 
Мне говорят, что первый вариант неправильный, но можно же сказать "Уровень чувствительности один из самых высоких в мире", почему же тогда нельзя поменять слова местами? В первом случае "уровень" - подлежащее, объект, уровень - какой? - один из самых высоких. Во втором случае "уровней" - субъект (дополнение...?), один - из чего? - из уровней, уровней каких? - самых высоких в мире.

Как правильно?

Comment: А хороший вопрос... Ваши критики неправы, это точно. С обоснованием у меня сейчас туго, не очень понимаю, с какой стороны надо обосновыать то, что достаточно очевидно само по себе. ))) Но я уверен, сейчас найдутся желающие ответить.  Ну или я завтра на свежую голову сформулирую.

Answer (score 1):

Полное предложение: Уровень чувствительности –  (2) **один из самых высоких в мире УРОВНЕЙ чувствительности.**

Перестройка предложения:

Сокращение:  Уровень чувствительности – один из самых высоких в мире (уровней чувствительности).

Инверсия:  (1) **Один из самых высоких в мире  УРОВЕНЬ чувствительности**

Это разговорный вариант: «один из самых высоких»  является определением в препозиции.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, в качестве подзаголовка лучше все-таки остановиться на более ясном "Один из самых высоких в мире уровней чувствительности". А "Один из самых высоких в мире уровень чувствительности", действительно, допустимо, но, как мне кажется, требует какого-то дополнения (уровень чувствительности у кого?) и знака препинания. В противном случае, после первого прочтения воспринимается так, будто вы "уровни" в женском роде просклоняли. Думаю, мой ответ дополнят.

Answer (score 0):

"Один из самых высоких в мире уровень чувствительности" - если речь идет об уровне, то  *уровень* , потому что в единственном числе и первая часть предложения описывает именно его.

Если же "Один из самых высоких в мире уровней чувствительности", то можно добавить слово "среди": "Один из самых высоких в мире *среди* уровней чувствительности", но тогда не совсем понятно, о чем идет речь.